# Is there functorial point of view to differential operator?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, functoriality

This question is related to [differential operator in noncommutative geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12910/differential-operator-in-noncommutative-geometry). I wonder whether there is any approach to differential operator that taking differential operator as a functor? I think it might be easier to do localization from the functorial point of view.

Comment: A. Don't post two questions one immediately after the other.  B.  In commutative algebra, the Kahler differentials are defined by an adjunction, that is, it's more than functorial, it's a universal construction.  Also, you should post some links (i.e., not links to the questions that you just posted) to relevant material, and also, you should add some motivation/work you've done yourself..  

Comment: Functor from what category to what category?

Comment: This is very vague; it seems outside the scope of what can usefully be asked on mathoverflow. There's been recent discussion of this at meta.

Comment: @YemonChoi Better late than never, I suppose, but yeah, the full-form of The adjunction is $A-\operatorname{Alg}/B \leftrightarrows B-\operatorname{Mod}$ (the first one is $A$-algebras with an $A$-algebra map to $B$) where $Y\mapsto \Omega_{Y/A} \otimes_Y B$ and its adjoint is given by $M\mapsto B\oplus M$.  I happened to be looking back over things to find the precise adjunction, and it's given as proposition 1.7 of Quillen's *Homology of Commutative Rings*